# Extract specific row from xlsx file to a list using python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I want to extract specific rows (assume for now that I already have the row number) from .xlsx file to a list. I addition, I don't know if it is possible but to take the first column as the list's name.

For example: the table I want to extract info from:

[image]

```
                   12/31/2020    12/31/2019    12/31/2018    12/31/2017
Revenue          1.823500e+11  1.614020e+11  1.369580e+11  1.110240e+11
Revenue Growth   1.298000e-01  1.785000e-01  2.336000e-01  2.373000e-01
Cost of Revenue  8.473200e+10  7.189600e+10  5.954900e+10  4.558300e+10
Gross Profit     9.761800e+10  8.950600e+10  7.740900e+10  6.544100e+10
```

If it is possible I want to get the info in this order: `Revenue = ["1.8235E+11", "1.61402E+11", "1.36958E+11" , "1.11024E+11"]`

I have already tried using xlrd to get this job done but I always get a message

> xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

Thanks in advance and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `openpyxl` then use `read_excel`:

```
# Python env: pip install openpyxl
# Anaconda env: conda install openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', index_col=0, engine='openpyxl')
print(df)

# Output:
                   12/31/2020    12/31/2019    12/31/2018    12/31/2017
Revenue          1.823500e+11  1.614020e+11  1.369580e+11  1.110240e+11
Revenue Growth   1.298000e-01  1.785000e-01  2.336000e-01  2.373000e-01
Cost of Revenue  8.473200e+10  7.189600e+10  5.954900e+10  4.558300e+10
Gross Profit     9.761800e+10  8.950600e+10  7.740900e+10  6.544100e+10
```

To extract the row `Revenue`, use:

```
Revenue = df.loc['Revenue']
```

Comment: Not quite, my intention was to get values of only one header such as revenue, and not all the table. I know that xlrd had a command '.row_values()'  do you know if is there anything similar in pandas and openpyxl?

Comment: `df.loc['Revenue']` gives you the row `Revenue`